# How prototype inheritance can affect method overriding in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Here’s the code,

```js
function extend(child, parent) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
  child.prototype.constructor = child
}

//Super Class
var Mobile = function() {}

//Prototype Method
Mobile.prototype.show = function() {
  return "Super Class Method";
}

//Sub class 
var Samsung = function() {}

extend(Samsung, Mobile);
Samsung.prototype.show = function() {
  return "Sub Class Method";
}

var sam = new Samsung();
document.write(sam.show()); //displays "Sub Class Method"
```

```js
function extend(child, parent) {
  child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype);
  child.prototype.constructor = child
}

//Super Class
var Mobile = function() {}

//Prototype Method
Mobile.prototype.show = function() {
  return "Super Class Method";
}

//Sub class 
var Samsung = function() {}
Samsung.prototype.show = function() {
  return "Sub Class Method";
}

extend(Samsung, Mobile);

var sam = new Samsung();
document.write(sam.show()); //displays "Super Class Method"
```

When I extend Samsung.prototype with Mobile.prototype before initializing the prototype method show() for Samsung, I get to see the show() method of Samsung.prototype, But writing it after initialization provides me with show() method of Mobile.prototype. Could someone please explain why is this happening as I'm new to JavaScript?

Comment: You code shows expected result. Can you add how and where you run `extend(child, parent)` to reproduce your issue?

Comment: In the second case, you *overwrite* the child prototype thus wiping out anything there was on it.

Comment: @yqlim, the first code snippet I've mentioned `extend(child, parent)` above prototype method show() for Samsung, while in the second one it's after the show() method for Samsung, thus causing two different outputs for both similar looking scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note about the first code snippet:

This pattern is called `behavior delegation`, the parent and child prototypes are linked together using your `extend` function, they're not copy of each others they are the same, but when you assign a new value to a property that already exist in the prototype chain, you shadow it and the new value will be used whenever you ask for it and not the value from the parent prototype.

In the second code snippet after creating a `show` method for the child, you override the whole prototype object all over again, and it's a normal result because you manually made its prototype to point to the new parent prototype.

Comment: Oh alright that explains everything. Thankyou, that helped a lot.